# Mercurial clone multiple repositories

Tags: mercurial, clone

Is there a way to clone multiple projects at the same time?

I have this project that contains multiple extensions each extension is on a different repo, I would like to be able to clone all extensions with one call. Is there a way to pipe URLs into gh clone command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about basic scripting, something like:

```
for repo in repo1 repo2 repo3 
do 
    hg clone $repo
done
```

Comment: Just wanted to know if there was a mercurial extension or some way of doing it. that is what i currently do. thanks.

Comment: Presumably if hg did it, it could do error checking and prevent incomplete sets or repos from being completed.  It could have reasonable behavior if you ran it on a director with a subset of the repos, etc, etc.   But I don't know of a way to do that so far, so the script is the best for now IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

If the extensions all belong to your "main" project anyway, why not make them [subrepositories](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Subrepository)?

Quote from the link:

> Subrepositories is a feature that allows you to treat a collection of repositories as a group. This will allow you to clone, commit to, push, and pull projects and their associated libraries as a group.

Comment: not my project. So i don't control how it works, and I really do not want to be maintaining the clone, just fetching the parts that i need for my own projects.